# Creating a custom chart in React Native using CSS

Tags: css, react-native

I'm trying to create a 'half donut' chart in React Native, using only CSS. The chart below is what I'm trying to recreate, but the segments are proving difficult.

[image]

This is what I've got so far:
[image]

Using this code:

```
customChart: {
  width: 200,
  height: 100,
  borderTopLeftRadius: 100,
  borderTopRightRadius: 100,
  borderWidth: 50,
  borderStyle: 'solid',
  borderColor: '#eee',
  borderBottomWidth: 0,
  overflow: 'hidden'
},
```

I just can't seem to get the segments to work. Any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the right way, just put in the color sections. In the following example

```css
.criteriometer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-width: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom: 0 !important;
  border-right: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}

/* from right to left to solve z-index */
span:first-child {
  border-color: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  border-color: orange;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
span:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: green;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="criteriometer">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

[A CodePen for this, written in less.](http://codepen.io/Bloggerschmidt/pen/MpJBRr)